# SELECT only records which must fill two conditions

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql5

I have this table:

```
id type otherid
1   4     1234
2   5     1234
3   4     4321
```

As you can see there are 3 records, 2 of them belongs to otherid "1234" and got type of 4 and 5.

Last record belongs to otherid of "4321" and has only a type of 4.

I need to select all otherid that got only the type 4 and not the type5.

Example: after this select on that table the query shuould return only the record 3

Thanks

add1:

Please consider the TYPE can be any number from 1 up to 20.
I only need otherid that got type 4 but not type 5 ( except than that they can have any other type )

add2:

using mysql 5.1

Comment: your description is little flurry to me. What exactly you want the query to return? And what database youre using? By your description the query would be: SELECT * FROM table WHERE type = 4, but this conflicts with your example

Comment: are you saying you want all otherid values where all records with that same otherid only have a type of 4?

Comment: I am saying i want otherid that got 4 but not 5 (+ any other type that can be found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is by using a left join from where you exclude rows that have both type 4 and 5:

```
select a.*
from table1 a
    left join table1 b on b.otherid = a.otherid and b.type = 5
where a.type = 4 and b.id is null
```

Comment: You can see how this works if you remove the "and b.id is null" from the where clause and change the select into "select * " instead of "select a.* ". You will see we that rows with type 4 fall into two categories: the ones with otherid showing up in other rows with another type (thus b.id being not null) and the ones with the otherid not showing up with other types (and having b.id null).

Comment: Wait a moment... I tried this query in a sub query that i need but the total query took over 50 secs :( At this point i asked the full query here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060423/2-left-join-for-2-tables thanks if you wanna help

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `not exists` subquery:

```
select  distinct otherid
from    YourTable as yt1
where   yt1.type = 4
        and not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable as yt2
        where   yt1.otherid = yt2.otherid
                and yt1.type <> yt2.type  -- use this line for any difference
                and yt2.type = 5          -- or this line to just exclude 5
        )
```

Comment: the clause <> doesnt' work because there are many other type other than 4 and 5, But i only need records who got 4 and not 5 (+any other type available)

Comment: @yes123: Answer edited... not sure if you mean to exclude just 5 or basically anything that's not 4, so I left both lines in

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a workaround

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('|',type,'|') type,other_id FROM table GROUP BY otherid
) t WHERE type LIKE '%|4|%' AND type NOT LIKE '%|5|%'
```

Comment: +1 because it works fine! But can't accept this because it's too expensiveù

Comment: I know what you mean.. Thanks for the + though :)