# 2 Left join for 2 tables?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am on MySQL:

I have 2 table, one is the main table, the other is an accessory table that contains some information supporting the records of the main table.

Example:

table portal:

```
id title desc
12  "aaa" "desc"
13  "bbb" "desc"
[etc]
```

secondary table (omitting the primary id field)

```
type portalid
 x    12
 2    12
 3    12
 4    12
 5    12

 1    13
 2    13
 4    13
```

I need to select every record in the table portal that got a record in the secondary table with type = 4 but != 5.

Example:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM portal,secondary_table s
 WHERE portal.id=s.portalid 
   AND type of secondary_table is 4 and is not 5
```

Results:

In this case only the record 13 of portal should be returned because the record 12 got both type 4 and 5.

Please note I asked a similar question but considering only one table, and with that query took over 50 secs to be elaborated.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider rephrasing it using NOT EXISTS clauses.  If all you want are records from `portal`, then a double EXISTS clause will work and very clearly reveal the query intentions

```
SELECT * 
FROM portal
WHERE EXISTS (select * from secondary_table s1
              where portal.id=s1.portalid
              and s1.type=4)
AND NOT EXISTS (select * from secondary_table s2
                where portal.id=s2.portalid
                and s2.type=5)
```

However, due to how MySQL process EXISTS clauses (even though it is clearer), you can trade off clarify for performance using LEFT JOIN / IS NULL.  Please read the following link, however the performance of each query may vary with specific data distribution, so try both and use whichever works better for your data.

[NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

The LEFT JOIN / IS NULL form would be written

```
SELECT * 
FROM portal
JOIN secondary_table s1 ON portal.id=s1.portalid and s1.type=4
LEFT JOIN secondary_table s2 ON portal.id=s2.portalid and s2.type=5
WHERE s2.portalid IS NULL
```

The order of the tables (portal, inner, left) is to allow processing the first two tables (portal + secondary/type=4) and trimming the result set early before launching into the LEFT (outer) JOIN (that retains everything from the left side) for the existential test.

Comment: Wow... this query is faster by 300% than the joel's query. Accepted. And yes it's more readable. Maybe i don't have yet to learn LEFT/etc :D

Comment: I tested a query with IN and NOT IN.. isn't your query equal to this? `SELECT portal.* 
FROM portal
WHERE id IN (SELECT portalid FROM sec WHERE type = 4)  AND id NOT IN (SELECT portalid FROM sec WHERE type = 5)`

Answer (score 1):

This is why you should avoid the older `FROM A,B` syntax - it's less powerful with respect to certain things.  Use explicit join types (LEFT/RIGHT/INNER/FULL/CROSS) instead.

```
SELECT <columns>
FROM portal p
LEFT JOIN secondary s1 ON p.id=s1.portalid AND s1.type = 5
INNER JOIN secondary s2 ON p.id=s2.portalid AND s2.type = 4
WHERE s1.type IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use this query that's very similar to EXISTS of richard:

```
SELECT * FROM portal 
WHERE id IN (SELECT portalid FROM sec WHERE type=4) 
      AND id NOT IN (SELECT portalid FROM sec WHERE type=5)
```

imo it's even more readable.